# If $\sum |a_k|$ converges, then $\sum |a_k|/{k^p}$ converges for all $p\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

> Problem: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|$ converges, prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k|}{k^p}$ converges for all $p\geq0$. What happens if $p<0?$

Attempt: Suppose $\lim_{k→\infty}\frac{|a_k|}{k^p} = 0$  exists for all p greater than zero. Also given that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k|}{k^p}$ converges for all $p\geq0$, we have by the limit comparison test $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k|}{k^p}$ is convergent when $p\geq 0$. If $p<0$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k|}{k^p} = \infty$. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{|a_k|}{k^p}$ is divergent when p < 0.

Is this right? Please can anyone please help? Thank you

Comment: Checking a few simple, concrete, cases might help you to eliminate the desire to prove some dubious assertions...

Comment: what type of concrete cases?

Comment: I can't quite understand your argument for $p\geq 0$ case. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So it is convergent still convergent when p < 1. Is the first part ok?

Comment: "what type of concrete cases?" Tell us! On which simple examples of series do you test assertions about the convergence of series?

Comment: Since the we need to prove $\frac{|a_k|}{k^p}$ converges, its limit as n approaches infinity must be equal to zero thus it diverges. Since |a_k| converges, the product of |a_k| and its p series must converge, where it is known that a p series is convergent when p > 1. Hence $|a_k|/k^p$ is convergent.

Comment: Isn't this last comment confusing convergence of sequences and convergence of series, big time?

Answer (score 1):

If $p > 0$ then $k \ge 1$ implies $k^p \ge 1$.  Thus $\dfrac{|a_k|}{k^p} \le |a_k|$ for all $k$ and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|$ converges by the comparison test.

Your statement if $p < 0$ is false.  $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k^{-3}$ converges, but so does $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{-3}}{k^{-1}}=\sum_{k = 1}^\infty k^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

Case $p>0: \ \exists n_0 >n \ \forall n$ s.t. $ |a_n| = b_{n \geq n_0} < 1$ - this is the criteria for convergence. Clearly if $p>0 \ b_n >\frac{b_n}{n^p} = c_n$, therefore $\sum_n c_n$ converges by comparison test.

Case $p<0$: take e.g. $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{2}}}$ and $p=-\frac{1}{2}$. What do you get?